# Adding data to a scrollview/table

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, macos

I have an NSCrollView that contains an NSTableView. It has 3 columns and 4 rows. I have 4 NSStrings with content that I need to copy into the scrollview.

Using Xcode 4 I tried connecting the table or the NSTextFieldCell and then adding the text via

```
[_Cell1 setStringValue:MyString];
```

But nothing happens. It doesn't get updated.

Any way to do this?
Thank you.

EDIT:

I found [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521309/cocoa-bindings-in-xcode-4) to a similar question. I still am confused but after reading Apple's example about bindings I can only say that this *does not* make any sense, so much code to achieve something so simple. That's the problem with everything being an object and with OOP in general.

Any *simple* samples out there? I don't even know how to start setting this or connecting the gazillion things you need to connect to start working with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't "add" or "set" the content of a table view. Like most view objects, a table view doesn't store content; it depends on a controller to provide content when it needs it.

There are two options:

- **Data source:** simplest, easiest to understand
- **Binding to an array controller:** harder to understand, but less work to implement

The best Apple resource on the subject: [Populating Cell-Based Table Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingCellTables/PopulatingCellTables.html) from the *Table View Programming Guide*. If you're struggling, I suggest you start with the data source option. It'll be just a few lines of code, and you can adapt the simple samples from that document.

To populate the table, you need to implement these two methods:

```
– numberOfRowsInTableView:
– tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:
```

And to change the data, you'll need to implement one more:

```
- tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:
```

You'll need to set your controller as the data source for the table view in interface builder. And the correct protocol for this is `NSTableViewDataSource`, not `NSTableViewDelegate`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the NSTableViewDelegate. That's a set of methods the NSTableView calls to get the data that it should display. You just have to declare the delegate object of the tableview.

[Delegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

[NSTableView Tutorial](http://juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/animatedPaint/025-NSTableView.pl)

Comment: Thanks, but all that code just to show a string on a table? Any other way to just display data in a grid without having to declare a zillion lines of code just to copy a string?

Comment: When you just want to show one string you probably should reconsider using a NSTableView.

Comment: It's not one string, its several. Each string fits on the columns.

Comment: Yep, use the NSTableViewDelegate.

Comment: Thanks but to show a simple string ordered on a table this is an overkill. 100 lines of code to show a string?

Comment: I guess we are not going to go anywhere with this. Thanks for trying anyway, I appreciate it.

Comment: Anyway, this is beside bindings the best solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `NSArrayController` and bind the table columns' value bindings to the array controller's arranged objects. Then add the values you want to display to the array controller.

Comment: Do you have a sample of this? Or can you point me to one? I'm a C programmer that has to deal with obj-c and cocoa and so far i'm not very sure I understand the idea behind it. Thanks!

Comment: I don’t know any example that shows this specific use case. But those are just very basic Cocoa patterns. [This](http://homepage.mac.com/mmalc/CocoaExamples/controllers.html) is a good resource on bindings, but as always the official documentation is always a good starting point.